# How to upload Visual Studio SQL server LocalDB to Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I just finished my first website on Visual Studio, using LocalDB with 30 tables and Identity. Then, I tried to move this website to Azure and I just got success to move the app. Unfortunately, the LocalDB is not recognized by Azure. What do I need to do to upload the database schemes and data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can migrate your on-premises database to Azure SQL database using SQL Server 2012(SQL Server 2017 and 2019 might face compatibility issues) and **SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)**.

Firstly, you need to attach your existing database with SSMS. [Follow the link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6222/sql-server-attach-and-detach-database-examples/).

**Follow the below steps in SSMS once your database attached.**

1. Right click on the database you want to migrate. Select **Task** and from dropdown options select **Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database**

[image]

2. Click on Next on pop-up window. On the very next window you will get options to connect your Azure SQL Server. **Provide your Azure SQL server name, server credentials and click on Connect.**

[image]

3. Provide the database name you want to give in Azure SQL Server. Fill the Azure SQL Database settings as per your requirement. Click on Next.

[image]

4. Lastly, you will get a summary of all the settings you have done. Click on **Finish** to migrate the database.
5. Once your database migrated successfully, you will get summary with **Operation Complete** message. Click on close. Your database has been migrated.
6. Check on your Azure Portal to check the migrated database.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your full reply. I was making a mistake in step 2. Now, everything is working.