# offline DMS migration from Azure SQL VM to Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, data-migration, azure-sql

I am migrating my databases from Azure SQL VM to Azure SQL DB using offline migration but while migrating I am getting a error i.e " Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataMigration.Models.ODataError"

I am using powershell script to migrate the database.
I don't know what is wrong in this and why am getting this error.
I have attached the error screenshot herein.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/280775/azure-dms-issue39failed-input-validation39.html) on Microsoft Q&A, the issue could be in relation to different collation on the source and destination DB's. I recommend you to raise a support ticket if possible.

Alternatively, you can use SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) to migrate the Database.

Install the SSMS in your local machine and connect to the Azure SQL VM by following [connect to SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-vm-create-portal-quickstart#connect-to-sql-server) steps in the tutorial.

Once you are connected with the server, follow the steps as mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68640542/how-to-upload-visual-studio-sql-server-localdb-to-azure/68740416#68740416) to migrate the database to Azure SQL Database.

Comment: From my experience you will generally get better (or at least easier to find) error debugging using SSMS as well.