# Login failed after moving sharded database from self-hosted to Azure Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sitecore

Is there a proper way to move a SQL Server 2016 sharded database from self-hosted to Azure Database?

I have a SQL Server 2016 sharded database that is part of the platform (Sitecore 10) I'm working with. It has a Shard Map Manager database and two Shard databases. I want to migrate the databases from self-hosted to Azure Database.

When the database is in a SQL Server Instance, it has one login mapped to the Shard Map Manger user and both Shard users. Everything works great. Since Azure Database does not use logins the same way and the databases are partially contained, I created separate users in each database in Azure with the same name and password.

Next, I migrated the schema with Azure Data Migration Services and then the data. There are some stored procedures that Sitecore provides to setup permissions and I ran those.

Finally, I updated the ServerName and DatabaseName fields in the `[__ShardManagement].[ShardsGlobal]` table for the ShardMapManager DB and the `[__ShardManagement].[ShardsLocal]` table in both Shard databases to match the new server and database names.

When I updated the app to use the new database, it spewed errors into the log, ultimately tracking to a failed login for the user. There are 13 other databases for the app which were also migrated and work fine, only the sharded database does not work in the app. I ran a PowerShell script that tests the connection string for all of the databases. All of the connection strings were successful. Backing out only the connection strings for the sharded database fixes the errors proving that the connection to the sharded databases is the problem.

What did I do wrong and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is only to migrate the databases from local to Azure, the best possible way is to use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

The advantage is that you can mention the new database name on Azure while migrating itself and hence no need to change later. But just make sure same named database shouldn't available already in Azure SQL Server.

You can follow the migration steps from my this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68640542/how-to-upload-visual-studio-sql-server-localdb-to-azure/68740416#68740416).

Also, my suggestion is to go through the official documents [Assessment rules for SQL Server to Azure SQL Database migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/migration-guides/database/sql-server-to-sql-database-assessment-rules), [Troubleshoot connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). I'm sure you will find the useful insights there which could help to make migrated database work properly with  the apps.